# Getting to specific parent of given element (in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I'm trying to do draggable to-do list and I run into this problem.
Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="to-do-element editing" draggable="true">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
        <span><span class="index">1</span>.</span>
        <span class="to-do-text"></span>
        <input type="text" class="to-do-input" placeholder="Click to add text."/>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button type="button" class="save-button icon-checkmark" data-button="save"></button>
        <button type="button" class="edit-button icon-pencil" data-button="edit"></button>
        <button type="button" class="delete-button icon-cross" data-button="delete"></button>
        <button type="button" class="move-up-button icon-arrow-up2" data-button="move-up"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="move-down-button icon-arrow-down2" data-button="move-down"></button>
        <button type="button" class="cross-out-button icon-strikethrough" data-button="cross-out"></button>
        <button type="button" class="uncross-out-button icon-undo" data-button="uncross-out"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
thisDiv.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
});

thisDiv.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.querySelector('.index').innerText);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text', e.target.querySelector('.index').innerText);;
});

thisDiv.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
    console.log(document.querySelector('.to-do-element:nth-of-type(' + e.dataTransfer.getData('text') + ')'));
    console.log(e);
    document.querySelector('#to-do-list').insertBefore(document.querySelector('.to-do-element:nth-of-type(' + e.dataTransfer.getData('text') + ')'), e.target);
})
```

The thing is `e.target` is too specific, I want to know which  I'm pointing at, but if I'm pointing exactly at span, it returns me span etc. I thought of using something like `.parentElement` but that doesn't help. I could loop `.path` and compare, but I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: `e.currentTarget` contains a reference to the element the event was actually attached to.

Comment: try e.currentTarget

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! :)